# How to finish the race_ function?

Tags: haskell

I want to finish the [`race_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.0.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:race) function but I don't know how to do that.

This is the code I have right now:

```
mainLoop :: Handle -> String -> IO ()
mainLoop handle username = do
    _ <- race_ fromServer toServer

    putStrLn "Race is done"
    return ()

    where
        fromServer = forever $ do
            line <- hGetLine handle
            putStrLn $ "Server: " ++ line

        toServer = do
            line <- getLine
            case line of
                ":quit" -> do
                    --hPutStrLn handle "blabla"
                    return ()
                _       -> do
                    hPutStrLn handle $ line
                    toServer
```

If I uncomment the line `hPutStrLn handle "blabla"` the user will see `Race is done` when he types `:quit`. Without that line the program just hang when the user types `:quit`.

I feels wrong to use `hPutStrLn handle "blabla"` just to finish the `race_`. I assume that there exists a better function to finish the `race_` function. Any idea?

I find it strange that a simple `return ()` doesn't work since both `hPutStrLn` and `return` returns an empty IO action.

Full context can be found [here](https://github.com/s4wny/Haskell-TCP-chat/blob/master/client.hs#L42). The handle is created by `handle <- connectTo "localhost" (PortNumber 4000)`. The server is created in [server.hs](https://github.com/s4wny/Haskell-TCP-chat/blob/master/server.hs#L48). I'm running this code on Windows 7 in "Git bash" (msysgit) with `runhaskell`.

Answer (score 1):

Used in context

```
import System.IO
import Control.Concurrent.Async
import Control.Monad

main = do
    h <- openFile "./a" ReadWriteMode
    mainLoop h "user"
    hClose h
```

this works fine also without hPutStrLn - what did you do? (where ./a is a large file, like "dmesg > a")

Comment: Full context can be found [here](https://github.com/s4wny/Haskell-TCP-chat/blob/master/client.hs#L42). The handle is created by `handle <- connectTo "localhost" (PortNumber 4000)`. The server is created in [server.hs](https://github.com/s4wny/Haskell-TCP-chat/blob/master/server.hs#L48).